# How do I import functions in .py files located in different folders using import

Tags: python, python-import

I have this directory

```
---App
-----Main.py
-----SubFolder1
-------Function1.py
-----SubFolder2
-------Function2.py
-----SubFolder3
-------Utility.py
```

I have some functions in Utility, which I need to import to Main and to Function1

In main.py i use this pseudocode

```
from SubFolder3.Utility import SomeFunction

SomeFunction()
```

How I can import SomeFunction from Utility.py into Function1.py
I don't have any idea how import work in python, despite of reading documentation and countless stackoverflow question treads.

P.S. I can't move Utility.py into SubFolder1 + I need to import SomeFuncion2 from Utility.py to Function2.py

I used literaly everything, that i could find in the internet. Some sys.path nonsense and various staff with init.py files. Maybe I do this wrong, idk

Comment: What do you intend to be the top-level package(s)? `App`? The directories inside of `App`? And remember, Python imports _do not navigate directories_. Imports are only ever resolved by searching the Python path. If you want your packages to be importable, you _must_ put the directory containing them on the Python path. This is usually done by either installing your code as a distribution package or by ensuing that the containing directory is your CWD.

Comment: I need a working import inside the App folder, I have no intention of importing anything from App outside of that folder, so I assume the top-level package will be App.
But I still haven't figured out how relative import works

Comment: There are no relative imports in your question. But in any case, this question may be helpful: [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/11082165)

Comment: Did you see [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#relativeimports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#relativeimports)? `from ..SubFolder3.Utility import SomeFunction`? But I imagine you need some `__init__.py`'s in the directories.

Comment: I recive this error message while i try this: "attempted relative import with no known parent package"

i have __ init __.py file in App, and in every SubFolder for sure

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set a current work directory to 'SubFolder3':

```
import  os
os.chdir('SubFolder3')
```

and then import the function

```
from Utility import SomeFunction
```

?

Comment: It accures this error: "No module named 'Utility'" - I dont know why, i wrote into os.chdir like everything, but it cannot see my file, and i dont understand why

Comment: Can you run os.getcwd() to see your current working directory?

Comment: Yup, i do that in Utility(print(os.getcwd())), and wrote it into path in my folder. Anyway - it gives me this error message.

Comment: You don't need to use Utility() here, just run print(os.getcwd()).

Comment: I print that, and it dont work
UPD: It dont work and I don't know why. It's just dont see my file in folder, despite of os.chdir('SubFolder3')

Answer (score 0):

This works.. As Brian mentioned in the comments - no relative imports.

```
APP
__init__.py
main.py
---Sub1
     __init__.py
     Func1.py
---Sub2
     __init__.py
---Sub3
     __init__.py
     Utility.py
```

---

main.py

```
from Sub1 import Func1
```

---

Func1.py

```
from Sub3.Utility import somefunc

somefunc()
```

---

Utility.py

```
def somefunc():
    print(__name__,'somefunc')
```

---

```
PS C:\App> py -m main
Sub3.Utility somefunc
PS C:\App>
```

---

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49375740/2823755) to [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/11082165) (for the billionth time): If you edit each `__init__.py` to modify sys.path then Func1 will run standalone. I only chose that answer's solution as it was very easy but I suspect that solutions in other answers might be *better* or more robust depending on your circumstances.

All `__init__.py`'s

```
import os, sys; sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

---

```
PS C:\App> py  -m main      
Sub3.Utility somefunc
PS C:\App> py  -m Sub1.Func1
Sub3.Utility somefunc
PS C:\App>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But there some strange bug - it works only when i import function1 to main, but when i try to run Function1 - it dont see utility
It's not nessasry to get rid of it, but i would like why it's happening

Comment: Ahh well I guess I need to finish reading through [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/11082165).